# splitAt '-' in scala

Tags: string, scala, higher-order-functions

I need to return two lists, the list of Strings up to and including the first line containing a ’-’ and then the remaining elements.

so i've been trying lst.splitAt('-') but it keeps doing

```
 scala> val lst = List(" Hi this is - a test")
 lst: List[String] = List(" Hi this is - a test")

 scala> lst.splitAt('-')
 res8: (List[String], List[String]) = (List(" Hi this is - a test"),List())
```

how can i fix this so that i will get (List(" Hi this is -),List( a test")) ?

Comment: You're splitting the list.  You need to split the string it contains.

Comment: @DonRoby how would i be able to target the string within the list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The argument to `List`'s splitAt is an `Int`. your '-' is being coerced to 45 and trying to split the list at index 45.

You can do this for a single string:

```
"hello-test-string".split('-')
```

The result of this (in sbt) is:

```
res0: Array[String] = Array(hello, test, string)
```

You can map this function over a list of strings if you want:

```
List("hello-test-string", "some-other-cool-string").map(_.split('-').toList)
```

The result of this is:

```
res1: List[List[String]] = List(List(hello, test, string), List(some, other, cool, string))
```

Comment: is it possible to do it without using Arrays and just get (list(), list()) ? @TimDestan

Comment: Sure, you can map toList as well... editing my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider `span` together with `unzip` like this,

```
lst.map(_.span(_ != '-')).unzip
```

which delivers

```
(List(" Hi this is "),List("- a test"))
```

Note that `span` bisects a collection (in this case each string in the list) up to the first element that does not hold a condition (equality to `'-'` here).

**Update**

For including the `'-'` char, we may define a `takeUntil` method on strings, for instance as follows,

```
implicit class StringFetch(val s: String) extends AnyVal {
  def takeUntil(p: Char => Boolean) = {
    val (l,r) = s.span(p)
    val (rl,rr) = r.span(!p(_))
    l + rl
  }
}
```

Hence

```
lst.map(_.takeUntil(_!= '-'))
res: List[String] = List(" Hi this is -")
```

Comment: is there anyway to have the "-" in the first list?